# Android 4.4 KitKat - Webview - Reload webpage, but remember location

Tags: android, webview, hyperlink, android-4.4-kitkat, webviewclient

Android 4.4 Webview - Re-load re-created webpage, but remember location

I have an app that builds a big html file containing lots of text with some hyperlinks, which when clicked, are picked up by a WebViewClient and run some java code, which again re-create the big html, maybe with a tiny change, and put it back into the same webview.

In MainActivity, build the html string, and then put into webview...

```
    buf.append("lots of text before... <a href=\"w" + id + "\">something here</a> lots of text after ...");

    ...

    WebView webView;
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,buf.toString, "text/html", "utf-8",null);
```

In WebViewClient, pick up hyperlinks clicked

```
    public class TestWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        TestActivity testActivity;
        public TestWebViewClient(TestActivity main) {
            this.testActivity = main;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            String newUrl = url.substring(1,url.length()); 

            if (url.substring(0,1).equals("w")) { 
                mainActivity.doSomethingAndReCreateHtml(newUrl);
            }
        }
}
```

Before Android 4.4 and webview based on Crome, the webview would remember the location of the html in the webview (how far down the html page had been scrolled down), so when a link in the html was clicked, and the html recreated and reloaded, the webview would remember the location, and present the re-created html at the same place as when the hyperlink was clicked - almost like nothing had happend.

But now, in Android 4.4 and Crome webview, when a link is clicked, and the html recreated and reloaded, the webview DOES NOT remember the location, and present the beginning of the html, without scrolling down to the location where the link was clicked in the first place.

Any idea what to do in Crome webview to remember the location?